# How do I compress a text file in Ubuntu using Snappy

Tags: ubuntu, compression, codec

I have done an `sudo apt-get install snappy`  on Ubuntu 14.04 and now every time I try and run the command `snappy textfile.txt` to compress `textfile.txt`. I get an error saying:

> ** (snappy:14342): ERROR **: Error discovering URI: This appears to be a text file. 
>   Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Anyone have any clue why this happened?

If I am doing it wrong, please show me a proper way to compress the text file with snappy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You installed the snappy movie player and it complains when you try to open a text file instead of a media file.
To install the snappy compression library you have to

```
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev
```

There are no default command line tools for snappy compression, you have to make your own or install another tool (or be anal and create a Perl one liner). I use Python for compression or the wrapper found at https://github.com/kubo/snzip

Supported languages can be found here:
https://google.github.io/snappy/